# Postgres - Function to return the intersection of 2 ARRAYs?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In postgresql, you can use the && operator to return t (true) if two arrays have common members, i.e. they overlap. Is there a function/operator that will return what those common members are?

i.e. something like this

```
select arrray_intersection(ARRAY[1, 4, 2], ARRAY[2, 3]);
ARRAY[2]
```

Comment: Also note that the `&&` operator was introduced in version 8.2 some time after the introduction of arrays: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/functions-array.html

Answer (score 91):

[Since 8.4, there are useful builtins in Postgres](http://www.depesz.com/index.php/2008/11/14/waiting-for-84-array-aggregate-and-array-unpacker/) which make [the function from the first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756871/postgres-function-to-return-the-intersection-of-2-arrays/756923#756923) easier and possibly faster (that's what EXPLAIN tells me, anyway: "(cost=0.00..0.07 rows=1 width=64)" for this query vs. "(cost=0.00..60.02 rows=1 width=64)" for the original one).

The simplified code is:

```
SELECT ARRAY
    (
        SELECT UNNEST(a1)
        INTERSECT
        SELECT UNNEST(a2)
    )
FROM  (
        SELECT  array['two', 'four', 'six'] AS a1
              , array['four', 'six', 'eight'] AS a2
      ) q;
```

and yeah, you can turn it into a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION array_intersect(anyarray, anyarray)
  RETURNS anyarray
  language sql
as $FUNCTION$
    SELECT ARRAY(
        SELECT UNNEST($1)
        INTERSECT
        SELECT UNNEST($2)
    );
$FUNCTION$;
```

which you can call as

```
SELECT array_intersect(array['two', 'four', 'six']
                     , array['four', 'six', 'eight']);
```

But you can just as well call it inline too:

```
 SELECT array(select unnest(array['two', 'four', 'six']) intersect
              select unnest(array['four', 'six', 'eight']));
```

Comment: For your second to last example I am getting the error `function array_intersect(text[], text[]) does not exist`. The last example works fine though!

Comment: how can we make this case insensitive ?

Comment: To aid optimisation, you could mark the `array_intersect` function as `IMMUTABLE`.

Comment: Anyone knows TypeORM equivalent for this?

Answer (score 37):

Try `&` instead of `&&`

See [PostgreSQL Docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/intarray.html) for more.

Comment: Tested, doesn't work in stock, you need a extension installed to make it work. but +1 anyway .

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/contrib.html # need to read the data here

Answer (score 14):

just another method..

```
SELECT ARRAY( SELECT * FROM UNNEST( $1 ) WHERE UNNEST = ANY( $2 ) );
```

Comment: That worked perfect for me, because it preserves the order. Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

If you don't mind installing an extension, the [intarray extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/intarray.html) provides the `&` operator to do this as @dwc pointed out.:

```
SELECT ARRAY[1, 4, 2] & ARRAY[2, 3];
```

Returns `{2}`.

Comment: Which postgresql version are you using? With 9.6 I get the error below and I also can't find it in the docs. Or am I doing something wrong here?

```ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer[] & integer[]
LINE 1: SELECT ARRAY[1,4,2] & ARRAY[2,3]
                            ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.```

Comment: Ah, wait, as per https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/intarray.html, it is an extension to postgresql. It would be worth mentioning that.

Comment: Note that this extension is quite famous and seems to be supported by Heroku, Amazon RDS and probably others. One answer from 2009 by dwc was proposing exactly the same `&` operator but it did not provide a usage example.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION intersection(anyarray, anyarray) RETURNS anyarray as $$
SELECT ARRAY(
    SELECT $1[i]
    FROM generate_series( array_lower($1, 1), array_upper($1, 1) ) i
    WHERE ARRAY[$1[i]] && $2
);
$$ language sql;
```

It should work with any kind of array, and you can use it like this:

```
SELECT intersection('{4,2,6}'::INT4[], '{2,3,4}'::INT4[]);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT  ARRAY
        (
        SELECT  a1[s]
        FROM    generate_series(array_lower(a1, 1), array_upper(a1, 1)) s
        INTERSECT
        SELECT  a2[s]
        FROM    generate_series(array_lower(a2, 1), array_upper(a2, 1)) s
        )
FROM    (
        SELECT  array['two', 'four', 'six'] AS a1, array['four', 'six', 'eight'] AS a2
        ) q
```

Works on non-integer arrays too.

Answer (score 2):

aother option, for those using for example postgresql, is to take benefits of the jsonb_path_exists tool to check for example if at least one of the elements of an array is also available in another array!

assuming for example here below that we have a table activity_role containing a column "rights" format JSONB, in which we could find for example

table: activity_role

| id | rights |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"folders":["write","read","assign"]} |

if we want to check if for example id 1 has at least one of the following rights ['sign', approve', 'write'], we simply run

```
SELECT jsonb_path_exists(ar.rights, '$.folders[*] ? (@ == $requested_right)',jsonb_build_object('requested_right', array['sign', 'approve', 'write']) AS authorized FROM activity_rights ar WHERE ar.id = 1;
```

result will be

authorized

---

true

because at least 'write' matches in the array1 (rights->'folders') and in the array2  (  array['sign', approve', 'write']  )

Answer (score 0):

How the inline operation `&&` would look like in `SELECT` statement where we are selecting from a 2 tables and **filtering only where two array columns intersect** (at least 1 value)

```sql
SELECT
    table_1 .list::text[],
    table_2 .list::text[]
FROM
    table_1,
    table_2
WHERE
    table_1.list::text[] && table_2.list::text[]
```