# Rails custom search using postgresql advice

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, search

I would love some advice on what's the best direction to take with the following search criteria I need to implement in my passion project app:

- search field will take in a string, in this case it will be a question
- in my database i will have, as an example, 100 pre-written answers with title:string answer:text and tag:string
- the search will compare at least three keywords from the question, to three answer tags
- the search result will be displayed on the answers#index page and show only one answer

Would it be best to build something in jQuery that converts the :tag string into an array of tags? This way I could compare against indexes ...

I tried using ElasticSearch and spent around 5 hours trying to get it installed with no luck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the primary search matching criterion is `show answer that has three or more of the search terms as tags`, then this will be a little tricky to cleanly implement with Postgres.

There are a couple routes you could go, neither of which will execute as fast as an Elasticsearch query:

1. SQL Subquery on an AnswerTags table:

   > Something like:
   >
   > `SELECT answer_id`
   >
   > `FROM answer_tags`
   >
   > `WHERE tag_text IN (<list of query terms>)`
   >
   > `GROUP BY answer_id HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3`
   >
   > `ORDER BY COUNT(*) desc`
2. Use a Postgres-specific array type to keep all Tags in an Answer field.  Write a stored procedure to calculate tag intersection/overlap:

   > Some suggested approaches in this thread: [Postgres - Function to return the intersection of 2 ARRAYs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756871/postgres-function-to-return-the-intersection-of-2-arrays)

If you pursue Elasticsearch as a solution, you'll have much better performance (though if you only have 100 records, this may not be significant), and a more straightforward implementation path.  (See the [minimum_should_match parameter associated with the match query type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/query-dsl-match-query.html#_boolean)).

Elasticsearch also enables ***a lot more nuance*** in your matching logic and search features (e.g. tiebreaking cases where multiple records match, autosuggesting answer titles or tags, synonyms/stemming and other text normalization methods)

Elastic recently acquired a great Elasticsearch hosting company [Found.no](http://found.no) which is a good choice if you want to bypass installation/configuration tasks to get up and running immediately.  They offer a 14-day free trial, and Found being owned by Elastic, upgrades faster than any other ES hosts and includes premium plugins with each cluster instance.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Peter! I'll keep trying to install Elasticsearch