# PostgreSQL select items of an array that are not in another array

Tags: arrays, postgresql

PostgreSQL table with two integer array columns, say `a = [1,2,3,4]` and `b = [1,2,3,4,5,6]`. The items of `b` that are not in `a` are `5,6`, so as a query result I want an array `[5,6]`.

How to achieve this in PostgreSQL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Postgres - Function to return the intersection of 2 ARRAYs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756871/postgres-function-to-return-the-intersection-of-2-arrays)

Comment: see: intarray Operators on https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/intarray.html

Comment: so simple... with intarray extension installed, its simply `select a-b`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with `intarray` extension installed, one may simply `select a-b`, cp. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/intarray.html