# Intersect on two array_agg columns in the same row

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have a simple Postgres dataset that looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (day, person)
values
('Monday', 'A'),
('Monday', 'B'),
('Tuesday', 'A'),
('Thursday', 'B');
```

I then run a query that yields two array_aggs as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM (select day as d1,
             array_agg(distinct person) as agg1
      from mytable
      group by day) AS AA
   cross join
     (select day as d2,
             array_agg(distinct person) as agg2
      from mytable
      group by day) AS BB
```

which yields this dataset:

```
Monday, {A,B}, Monday, {A,B}
Monday, {A,B}, Thursday, {B}
Monday, {A,B}, Tuesday, {A}
Thursday, {B}, Monday, {A,B}
Thursday, {B}, Thursday, {B}
Thursday, {B}, Tuesday, {A}
Tuesday, {A}, Monday, {A,B}
Tuesday, {A}, Thursday, {B}
Tuesday, {A}, Tuesday, {A}
```

I would like to add a fifth column to this query that identifies that number of repeat entries in agg1 and agg2 across each row.

So for example, the first row would be 2 and the second row would be 1. I was hoping to do it as follows, but this gives me a ambiguous syntax error:

```
SELECT *, count(select unnest(agg1) intersect select unnest(agg2))
FROM (select day as d1,
             array_agg(distinct person) as agg1
      from mytable
      group by day) AS AA
   cross join
     (select day as d2,
             array_agg(distinct person) as agg2
      from mytable
      group by day) AS BB
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgresql has LATERAL.

Which can be used to do something with the content of fields on record level.

> ```
> create table mytable (day varchar(30), person varchar(1));
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO mytable (day, person)
> values
> ('Monday', 'A'),
> ('Monday', 'B'),
> ('Tuesday', 'A'),
> ('Thursday', 'B');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT *
> FROM (
>   select day as d1,
>              array_agg(distinct person) as agg1
>       from mytable
>       group by day) AS AA
>    cross join
>      (select day as d2,
>              array_agg(distinct person) as agg2
>       from mytable
>       group by day
> ) AS BB
> CROSS JOIN LATERAL 
> (
>    SELECT COUNT(*) AS MatchingPersons
>    FROM
>    (
>      SELECT unnest(agg1) person
>      INTERSECT
>      SELECT unnest(agg2)
>    ) q
> ) lat
> ```
>
> ```
> d1       | agg1  | d2       | agg2  | matchingpersons
> :------- | :---- | :------- | :---- | --------------:
> Monday   | {A,B} | Monday   | {A,B} |               2
> Thursday | {B}   | Monday   | {A,B} |               1
> Tuesday  | {A}   | Monday   | {A,B} |               1
> Monday   | {A,B} | Thursday | {B}   |               1
> Thursday | {B}   | Thursday | {B}   |               1
> Tuesday  | {A}   | Thursday | {B}   |               0
> Monday   | {A,B} | Tuesday  | {A}   |               1
> Thursday | {B}   | Tuesday  | {A}   |               0
> Tuesday  | {A}   | Tuesday  | {A}   |               1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=7eda86f9696e767e0f0f615a1c216793)*

Comment: @user2242044 Thx. Btw, you can get the same result if you use that query with the count as a correlated sub-query. `select *, (select count(*) ...) as matches from ...`.  But a correlated sub-query can only return 1 column. While with LATERAL the SQL is more readable, and you could include more calculated columns.

Answer (score 0):

Using the function from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5834576/6464308), you could write:

```
SELECT *, array_length(array_intersect(arr1, arr2), 1) AS repeat_count
FROM /* your query */
```