# Get matching elements from an array comparison

Tags: postgresql

I'm attempting to get matching elements regarding two arrays. I need to select them, so it essentially goes as follows

**Contstraints:**

1. Using Postgres 12, with no plugins.
2. String arrays, not int.

SQL I've come up with:

```
SELECT
    elb.1,
    elb.2,
    esp.1,
    esp.2
FROM
    schema.table1 as esp
    JOIN schema.table2 elb ON (elb.1 = esp.1)
WHERE
    (esp.3 && ('{DHE:false, DHE:true, CAM:true}'::text[]))
```

Let's assume esp.3 ==

```
'{
    BHE:false,
    DHE:true,
    CMD:true,
}'
```

What is the cleanest way to get that matching value *DHE:true* from these two arrays? I can't really alter the format of what i have here by much, so no functions etc.

I was really hoping to have something like:

```
SELECT
    elb.1,
    elb.2,
    esp.1,
    esp.2,
    diff
FROM
    schema.table1 as esp
    JOIN schema.table2 elb ON (elb.1 = esp.1)
WHERE
    select((esp.3 in any('{DHE:false, DHE:true, CAM:true}'::text[]))) as diff;
```

But i couldn't find any solution or variation on that. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Write a function `array_intersect` that uses `unnest` and joins.

Answer (score 0):

`any` only returns true or false so it can stop looking once it matches.

You can use the technique from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12828574/14660) to get the intersection of two text arrays.

```
SELECT
    elb.1,
    elb.2,
    esp.1,
    esp.2,
    ARRAY(
      SELECT *
      FROM UNNEST( esp.3 )
      WHERE UNNEST = ANY('{DHE:false, DHE:true, CAM:true}'::text[])
    ) as diff
FROM
    schema.table1 as esp
    JOIN schema.table2 elb ON (elb.1 = esp.1)
WHERE
    (esp.3 && ('{DHE:false, DHE:true, CAM:true}'::text[]))
```

You can DRY it up with a CTE to first take the diff, then check it.

```
with esp as (
  select
    1,
    2,
    ARRAY(
      SELECT *
      FROM UNNEST( 3 )
      WHERE UNNEST = ANY('{DHE:false, DHE:true, CAM:true}'::text[])
    ) as diff
  from schema.table1
)
select
  elb.1,
  elb.2,
  esp.1,
  esp.2,
  esp.diff
from
  schema.table2 elb
  join esp on (elb.1 = esp.1)
where cardinality(esp.diff) != 0;
```